# Non-null value in Kotlin produces nullpointerexception

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, kotlin-null-safety

I have an array of non-nullable values like this:

```
private val dogs = ArrayList{Dog}() // replace {} with <>
```

It is populated like this:

```
val dog = Dog()  
dog.name = “bob”  
dogs.add(dog)
```

There are up to 3 different methods that can populate it like this, depending on the code flow.
Once the array is filled, it is processed:

```
if (dogs.size > 0) {  
    Collections.sort(dogs, Dog.comparator)  
    for (i in dogs.indices) {  
        val dog = dogs[i]  
        dog.bark()  
    }  
}
```

All of this is done in AsyncTask doInbackground.

I’m intermittently getting the following exception when calling dog.bark():

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method com.myname.model.Dog.P()' on a null object reference
       at com.myname.util.RunnableAsync.doInBackground(SourceFile:5)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

In short, ArrayList of non-null objects sometimes contains a null object.
I’m trying to figure out how this can happen. I would expect  that Kotlin would complain if non-null value is added to the ArrayList and of course I’m not sure how this can happen in the first place as I only put non-null values in the array. Threading issues? Any ideas are welcome:) Thanks.

Comment: Your code never shows an instance of you calling `Dog.P()`. If you replaced your code with hypothetical code, don't do that. Post your actual code, and more of it than this.

Comment: This trace is from analytics service and it happens on a real customer device. The method name is obfuscated but it is the correct call. I cannot reproduce the issue in my test lab or I'd post the exact stack trace.

Comment: It's not possible to help then. Most crash reporting services will let you upload the mapping files for obfuscated apps, to get proper stacktraces.

Comment: As I said before, I matched the code to the stack trace without any ambiguity. I'm not sure what else could be of help in a stack trace. It is as complete as possible from the background thread.

Comment: I'm interested even in a generic idea (not specific to the code) on what can cause the ArrayList declared as containing non-null values to have nulls in Kotlin. For example, 2 threads accessing the array at the same time adding new elements. Can the 3rd thread reading the array get a null element while it is being updated by another thread?

Comment: Hi, I'm actually getting exactly same issue. Very curious on how this is going?

Answer (score 0):

Use  Collections.synchronizedList(ArrayList()).
The only explanation I could come up with is the threading issue which is fixed by synchronizing the collection.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types) related to null safety, the issue may be caused by:

> An uninitialized `this` available in a constructor is passed and used somewhere (a "leaking this").

In another word, the NullPointerException describe the object as not initialized yet. Only after initialization, the object on the caller side is non-null.

I saw the exception thrown in AsyncTask. You can check whether there may be some async task call `dog.P()` before it is initialized.